# why is this causeing a inf. loop?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

This part of the code gives a client that connects to the server an ID by checking if the ID is been used or not if it has been then check the next highest ID.  For some reason this is causing a never ending loop why is that?

```
        int IDcounter = 0;
        bool IDfound = false;
        bool IDused = false;
        while (!IDfound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current ID check " + IDcounter);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of clients " + clientList.Count);
            foreach (Client id in clientList)
            {
                if (id.ID == IDcounter)
                {
                    IDused = true;
                    IDcounter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!IDused)
            {
                client.ID = IDcounter;
                IDfound = true;

            }

        }

        clientList.Add(client);
```

Comment: Where is `IDcounter` assigned?

Comment: oh sorry right befor the IDfound, ill edit that in

Comment: If this is for assigning an identifier for use as a database key, that's not a very good idea.

Comment: no its not for use with a database, Its before the client actually logs in,  
T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an `else` to the final `if` statement:

```
        if (!IDused)
        {
            client.ID = IDcounter;
            IDfound = true;

        }
        else
        {
            // Reset the IDUsed status
            IDUsed = false;
        }
```

Consider what happens when you find that the first ID you check is taken by some client. You set `IDUsed` to `true`, and then `break` the loop. The `if (!IDUsed)` check is false (since the ID *was* used,) and so you repeat. But notice that you've never set `IDUsed` back to `false`. And in fact, there's nowhere in the loop that happens, and so you loop forever.

Comment: Omg i feel like an idiot lol, thanks for your help ill accept the answer when 4 mins is up

Comment: Wont this just in every case set IDUsed to false, do one more loop and then return with IDcounter being 1 in every case? Or is it just me. Afaik that doesn't really solve his problem.

Comment: @Rasive The `IDCounter` variable has increased by 1 at this point, so the next loop through the client list will either a) match a different client (at which point `IDUsed` will be back to `true`) or b) match no clients (which will leave `IDUsed` at `false`, and with an ID that is actually usable by the new client.)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to set Idused=false inside to loop

Answer (score 0):

You're only breaking out of your loop if you don't find the id.  If you do find the id, then IDused is true and IDFound stays false.